# Alexa Account Linking keeps Expiring

Tags: google-oauth, alexa-skills-kit

I am using Google oAuth for the Account Linking. It works perfectly fine when I link my account, I am able to discover the devices, get their state & turn them on/off. But after a while, it starts showing the message 'Server is unresponsive' and after a while, when I go to the Skill, it says 'Account Linking Required' in red, meaning that the linking has expired or been voided. I checked the google oAuth flow and I am infact receiving an accessToken and a refreshToken.

My skill settings :

Your Web Authorization URI*: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline

Access Token URI : https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

Default Access Token Expiration Time : 31536000

What can be causing this and what do I need to resolve this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This usually indicates that Alexa was unable to use the provided refresh token to grab a new access/refresh token pair.

-Ensure that the access token time to live (TTL) is more than 5 minutes.

-Ensure that your authorization server can successfully refresh the access/refresh token pair when presented with a refresh token by Alexa.

-Ensure that you are not invalidating refresh tokens too early - Alexa may take some time after the access token has expired to refresh the token, and if your authorization server has already invalidated the refresh token, Alexa will not be able to refresh the access/refresh token pair and your customer will have their account linking disabled.

More details here:
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa/account-linking/requirements-account-linking.html#access-token-uri-requirements

I would strongly recommend reading over the following blog and knowledge base articles. They cover the most common points of friction that Alexa developers encounter with account linking, as well as providing some tips on how to best debug your skill's account linking implementation:

Troubleshooting account linking blog: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/blogs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/2020/12/troubleshooting-common-account-linking-issues-with-alexa-skills